# Retrofit default thread

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I use `Retrofit` with `RxJava` in my Android app, and my code:

```
public void getConfig(NetworkSubscriber subscriber) {
    Observable<Config> observable = mApi.getConfig();
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}

public void getCode(String mobile, int type, NetworkSubscriber subscriber) {
    Observable<BaseMessageEntity> observable = mApi.getCode(mobile, type);
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

And i don't want to write `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` and 
`.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` every business method

How can i do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't want to specify the threads you want on every call, you can create a wrapper around `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` to set your threads for your by default.

```
public class RxThreadCallAdapter extends CallAdapter.Factory {

    RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxFactory = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create();
    private Scheduler subscribeScheduler;
    private Scheduler observerScheduler;

    public RxThreadCallAdapter(Scheduler subscribeScheduler, Scheduler observerScheduler) {
        this.subscribeScheduler = subscribeScheduler;
        this.observerScheduler = observerScheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public CallAdapter<?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        CallAdapter<Observable<?>> callAdapter = (CallAdapter<Observable<?>>) rxFactory.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit);
        return callAdapter != null ? new ThreadCallAdapter(callAdapter) : null;
    }

    final class ThreadCallAdapter implements CallAdapter<Observable<?>> {
        CallAdapter<Observable<?>> delegateAdapter;

        ThreadCallAdapter(CallAdapter<Observable<?>> delegateAdapter) {
            this.delegateAdapter = delegateAdapter;
        }

        @Override public Type responseType() {
            return delegateAdapter.responseType();
        }

        @Override
        public <T> Observable<?> adapt(Call<T> call) {
            return delegateAdapter.adapt(call).subscribeOn(subscribeScheduler)
              .observeOn(observerScheduler);
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it instead of `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()` in your builder --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(new RxThreadCallAdapter(Schedulers.io(), AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
    .build();
```

Comment: Thinks bro! You got me!

Comment: This errors if you do call within on of the threads (IE custom access management) ```return delegateAdapter.responseType();``` will return null pointer.

Answer (score 17):

To have a default scheduler for `subscribeOn` you can pass it as an argument straight to the `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` when creating your `Retrofit` instance:

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
      .client(okHttpClient)
      .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
.build();
```

(For RxJava1 use `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory`)

Got introduced in Retrofit 2.0.0

Comment: And `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io())` for rx java 2

Comment: This is good answer. But then we still need to remember to add `observeOn` in our code, for example in cases where we're updating views, which should be done on main thread.

Comment: Maybe. If you have your Activity/Fragment [observe a LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20androidx.lifecycle.Observer%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) of a ViewModel, as usually suggested, then `observe` ensures to be on the main thread automatically

Answer (score 6):

You can reduce it to one line using [`compose()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#compose(rx.Observable.Transformer)). For example, below is a modified version of your `getConfig()` method. It assumes you are using retrolambda.

```
public void getConfig(NetworkSubscriber subscriber) {
    Observable<Config> observable = mApi.getConfig();
    observable
            .compose(this::setupThreads)
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

The `setupThreads()` method would look like this:

```
private <T> Observable<T> setupThreads(final Observable<T> observable) {
    return observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

**A few references:**

- RxJava Wiki - [Transformational Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Implementing-Your-Own-Operators#transformational-operators)
- Dan Lew blog post - [Don't break the chain: use RxJava's compose() operator](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/)

Comment: thanks, i got it. but, that's no way to solve it by rx self?

Comment: @xuyanjun - `compose()` is a valuable part of RxJava so I'm not quite sure what you mean by "solve it by rx self". In this case `compose()` will allow you to re-use `setupThreads()` over and over without having to add `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` to every observable.